# multiple url path mapping in ingress for kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I  have a node app configured with a base url as "/api" which is serving as a backend and a react app which is serving as the frontend. I have deployed both the app as a service in ingress kubernetes.
Below is my ingress path mapping

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: vf-prod-ing
  annotations:
  
  namespace: prod
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts: 
    - test.example.com

  rules:
  - host: test.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: "/"
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: fe-service
            port:
                number: 80
      - path: "/feature"
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: fe-service
            port:
                number: 80
      - path: "/api"
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: be-service
            port:
                number: 80
```

The issue im facing is when i try to access test.example.com it works. but i try to access test.example.com/feature it shows 404. The api call test.example.com/api/getData works fine and returns a json response

I tried  updating the ingress to below, test.example.com and test.example.com/feature works but the api call test.example.com/api/getData doesnt seem to be going t backend service and getting some html response

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: vf-prod-ing
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
  
  namespace: prod
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts: 
    - test.example.com

  rules:
  - host: test.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: "/"
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: fe-service
            port:
                number: 80
      - path: "/(.*)"
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: fe-service
            port:
                number: 80
      - path: "/api(/|$)(.*)"
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: be-service
            port:
                number: 80
```

Can someone help me configure rightly so all url test.example.com, test.example.com/* or test.example.com/abc/* goes to the front end service  and test.example.com/api/**  goes to the backend service always..

My nginx verison

kubectl exec -it  -n prod -- nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.24.0

Comment: are you sure the 404 is coming from the ingress controller and not from your app? sounds like you get a request to your backend starting with /feature that your backend can't handle (but it's just a wild guess)

Comment: Why do you have those two `- path: "/"` and `- path: "/feature"` ingress rules? as both are going to `fe-service` only first one is enough

Comment: / is the base url of the website. However there are other public page for which i want to give direct access to those pages and doesnt want to always navigate from  base url  /

Comment: Can you check the links related to **[configuration](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/basic-configuration/)** and implementation of **Hostname [wildcards](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#hostname-wildcards)** which will be useful to you.

Comment: @whites11, in my local the url /feature is accessible . Only when deployed in the kubernetes with ingress , it shows 404 error. so i guess issue in the yml file

Comment: The issue seems to be with the annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2` Can you try to replace `/$2` with `/` and check if it is working. You can refer to the github [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/main/docs/examples/rewrite) for more information.

Comment: tried all combinations. nothing worked

Comment: The issue seems to be that the NGINX Controller is not compatible with the kubernetes version. You can confirm the supported versions with kubernetes [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx?tab=readme-ov-file#supported-versions-table).